# How to achieve Drag and drop the element from angular tree view structure to html table using ngDraggable module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In my project i have a tree view, here data is from the server in JSON format. Then I need to drag these elements(object) into a html table like structure. Based on the dragging element's width(property) this html table's cell width needs to be customized. Then the dragged elements in the html table should having the capability to drag and drop inside the html table.   I am doing using ngDroppable module but with no success. How can I achieve this?. Any guidance would be grateful.

Comment: Have you checked these?

https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/blob/master/example.html

https://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/vLaWLX

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the response. I am using this module only, but with this I could able to drop in a linear way I want to drop in a html table like structure at any cell where my cursor dropped the element.

Comment: Anyone know how to drop an element into a  div as a row and column based structure using ngDraggable module?

Comment: would be helpful if you can post your code or fiddle whatever you've tried so far.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Nithya_Neela/ux4e1ors/1/

Comment: Hey I just edited the example I mentioned earlier. See if this works for you: https://codepen.io/srv91/pen/oYQomo

Comment: Yes, it works. But when we dragged the element inside a particular cell, it replicated in all the cells, how can we restrict it.

Comment: Haha, you're not trying to understand whats happening in the code, right?
You need to understand that, its easy. Let me know if you could not

Comment: Ok, i will try to understand.